# Copy data from on premisses SQL to Azure SQL in real time

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory, real-time

I have two tables on an on premisses server that I'd like to have replicated in real time (not near real time).

After analyzing, the nearest thing I found was Azure Data Factory, which allows me to have a scheduled trigger which is near real time. What I'd like to achieve is really data that is in one place is also on the other place, no difference at all.

I could achieve this with distributed transactions when I was working with on premisses servers but since one of the is in the cloud, what else can I do to achieve realtime?

Thanks!

Comment: do you need 2-way replication or is one read only?

Comment: Do you have an application, or do you have to solve this in the database or with an external tool?  Are the tables large?  Do you mind having a pretty severe performance penalty for updating both databases in a transaction?  If you can tolerate a bit of latency, this is very easy to do with Transactional Replication. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/replication-to-sql-database

Comment: Hi guys thank you for your replies. One of the database can be readonly the aim is to high performance. Tables have a few thousands of records but update penalty is not an option unless it is made out of peak hours